# Mongo Java Driver Not able to connect to replica set

Tags: mongodb

when connection using mongo db driver with replica set it is giving warning that connecting to localhost as below mentioned. any idea why ?

```
Dec 21, 2013 2:47:49 PM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
WARNING: Server seen down: localhost/127.0.0.1:10001 - java.io.IOException - message: couldn't connect to [localhost/127.0.0.1:10001] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Dec 21, 2013 2:47:50 PM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
WARNING: Server seen down: localhost/127.0.0.1:10003 - java.io.IOException - message: couldn't connect to [localhost/127.0.0.1:10003] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Dec 21, 2013 2:47:52 PM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
WARNING: Server seen down: localhost/127.0.0.1:10001 - java.io.IOException - message: couldn't connect to [localhost/127.0.0.1:10001] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Dec 21, 2013 2:47:53 PM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
WARNING: Server seen down: localhost/127.0.0.1:10003 - java.io.IOException - message: couldn't connect to [localhost/127.0.0.1:10003] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Dec 21, 2013 2:47:54 PM com.mongodb.ConnectionStatus$UpdatableNode update
WARNING: Server seen down: localhost/127.0.0.1:10002 - java.io.IOException - message: couldn't connect to [localhost/127.0.0.1:10002] bc:java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoException: can't find a master
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.checkMaster(DBTCPConnector.java:514)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:174)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.say(DBTCPConnector.java:155)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:249)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:205)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:100)
    at mongo.Test.main(Test.java:33)
```

Comment: Ok, maybe a stupid question, but is mongodb really supposed to be running on localhost port 10001/10002/10003, or is the driver just confused and thinks that's the case?

Comment: while connecting with one node there is no issue but when we configure using ServerAddress it always connect to localhost. !!!!

Comment: Please show the relevant code and to which IPs + ports you want to connect

Comment: Code Pls. List<ServerAddress> list = new ArrayList<ServerAddress>();
  ServerAddress adress1 = new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 1234);
  ServerAddress adress2 = new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 1235);
  list.add(adress1);
  list.add(adress2);
  MongoClient client = new MongoClient(list);
  DB db = client.getDB("test"); ---- This works fine localhost but does not work for any ip other than localhost. Pls Help.

Comment: This should be correct. I'm using domain names instead of IPs for remote addresses, but this shouldn't make any difference, and it's working for me using the same configuration.